# How to add placeholder attribute to JSF input component?

Tags: jsf, placeholder

Shouldn't this line of code render a inputtext field with the placeholder text "fill me" when using html5?

```
<h:inputText placeholder="fill me" />
```

I do not see any placeholder text. I thought everything that was not JSF was passed to the browser for rendering?

Comment: You have to use one of the attributes supported by that tag. Or you can make your own custom component (or composite component) to support that attribute. You can see the list of valid attributes here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/inputText.html

Comment: @gurung: a composite is not possible if the standard components/renderers already don't support it. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen

Comment: @BalusC: Oh ya, I didn't even think about it that it's going to be the same component that will be using even in the composite comp. Thanks for the heads up again.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

> *I thought everything that was not JSF was passed to the browswer for rendering?*

This assumption is thus wrong. [Unspecified](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/) component attributes are ignored by the JSF renderers.

You have basically the following options to get it to work:

1. If you're already on JSF 2.2 or newer, set it as a [passthrough attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets009.htm#sthref393).

   ```
    <... xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">

    <h:inputText a:placeholder="fill me" />
   ```

   Note that I use a XML namespace prefix of `a` ("attribute") instead of `p` as shown in the tutorial, as it would otherwise clash with default XML namespace prefix `p` of PrimeFaces.
2. Implement a custom renderer for `<h:inputText>` wherein you explicitly check and write the attribute.
3. Implement a custom component which uses the aforementioned custom renderer.
4. Implement a JS based solution wherein you grab the element from DOM and explicitly set the attribute.
5. Look for a component library which supports this out the box. [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) for example has a [`<p:watermark>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/watermark.xhtml) for this purpose with nice JS based graceful degradation for browsers which does not support the `placeholder` attribute on inputs.

#### See also:

- [Custom HTML tag attributes are not rendered by JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666472/custom-html-tag-attributes-are-not-rendered-by-jsf)

Comment: [an implementaion for option one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859520/adding-custom-attribute-html5-support-to-jsf-2-0-uiinput-component)

Comment: gtk, we're using myfaces so I ended up subclassing org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlTextRenderer

Comment: @Sam: it's not JSF impl specific.

Comment: we're on JSF 1.2 and it looks like that requires 2.0, so I had to write my own. If we upgrade then I'll definitely switch to it.

Comment: here is the link for <p:watermark>: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/watermark.jsf

Answer (score 26):

You can achieve it either with `placeholder` attribute or with `p:watermark` if using Primefaces and JSF 2.0+ or, when JSF 2.2 available, you can use `pt:placeholder` attribute.

**Primefaces**

```xml
<p:inputText id="search_input_id" value="#{watermarkBean.keyword}" 
    required="true" label="Keyword" placeholder="fill me" />
```

Legacy browser support (Adds JS solution):

```xml
<p:inputText id="search_input_id" value="#{watermarkBean.keyword}" 
    required="true" label="Keyword" />  
<p:watermark for="search_input_id" value="fill me" />
```

**JSF 2.2 (without PF)**

```xml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:inputText value="#{bean.value}" pt:placeholder="fill me"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Which basically generates an HTML 5

```xml
<input placeholder="fill me" />
```

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18250980/1199132) answer.

Answer (score 10):

With JSF 2.2 you can passthrough unspecified attributes like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
>

    <h:inputText p:placeholder="fill me"></h:inputText>
```

Comment: In JSF 2.3 Eclipse says: Can't find facelet tag library for uri when I use    xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"

Answer (score 8):

In case you are using **RichFaces**, starting in version 4.3, you can use the tag "rich:placeholder" for this purpose as shown [here](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=placeholder). Basically:

```
<h:inputText id="myInput">
    <rich:placeholder value="My placeholder text"></rich:placeholder>
</h:inputText>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{login.userId}" class="aux1" />
<h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{login.password}" redisplay="true" class="aux2" autocomplete="off" />

<script>
  $('.aux1').attr('placeholder', 'Introducir Usuario');
  $('.aux2').attr('placeholder', 'Introducir Contraseña');
</script>
```

With jQuery, this works right for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy and browser independent code as BaluSc told, 
In primefaces, use `p:watermark` to get the required functionality.
Official Demo is [HERE](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/watermark.xhtml)

Answer (score 0):

Use primeface 4.0. Versions below this version do not support the placeholder attribute.

1. use name space `xmlns:pt="http://java.sun.com/jsf/passthrough"`.
2. `p:inputTextarea id="textAreaValue" pt:placeholder="your text"`

   don't insert a new line in `inputTextArea`.

Comment: The `placeholder` attribute is related with the JSF version, not with the PF one.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to render an input field with a placeholder text is to use the **elementary input tag**

Example:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Fill me" value="#{EL}"/>
```

**Note:** you dont have to include any namespaces

Answer (score -1):

```
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.value}" placeholder="fill me"/>
</h:body>
```

This works right for me, try it!

Comment: <h:inputText> does not have any attribute like placeholder then how it worked for you...!!!???