# How to display placeholder for h:inputSecret

Tags: css, html, placeholder

I have been trying to display `placeholder` for `h:inputSecret` but not able to do it. There is no `placeholder` attribute is exist for `h:inputSecret` Its a small issue but i didn't find any solution.

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 1):

> *I thought everything that was not JSF was passed to the browswer for rendering?*

This assumption is thus wrong. [Unspecified](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/) component attributes are ignored by the JSF renderers.

You have basically the following options to get it to work:

1. Implement a custom renderer for `h:inputText`.
2. Implement a custom component (with a custom renderer).
3. Implement a JS based solution.
4. Look for a component library which supports this out the box. PrimeFaces for example has a [`<p:watermark>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/watermark.jsf) for this purpose with nice JS based graceful degradation for browsers which does not support the `placeholder` attribute on inputs.

[StackOverflow same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494264/where-is-the-placeholder-text-going-when-using-jsf-and-inputtext)

[Stack overflow similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061072/hinputtext-jsf-does-not-render-the-placeholder)