# Default text (placeholder) in InputText component

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, placeholder

[image]

I want to display a default Informative text in JSF/Primefaces **inputText** component.

- This text should disappear when user clicks on Text field.
- Appear when he clicks outside without typing anything.
- **If user submits the form without any value, this default value should not be set to   Bean's Property.**

I'm aware that setting the default value to BeanProperty in ManagedBean will work,but I don't want that.
Please suggest any JQuery tweaks,If possible.
Redirect me to right Question if this question is Duplicate.

Comment: In basic HTML terms, this thing is called "placeholder". This new search keyword should give you clues.

Comment: `<p:watermark for="search_input_id" value="search" />`

Comment: @XtremeBiker -why not post an answer?

Comment: Done. As @BalusC says a clue keyword for this question is the **placeholder** word. I suggest Kishor P changing the question title to include this in some way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Primefaces** provides a `placeholder` attribute in its latest versions which you can use for `p:inputText`. Also, there is a [`p:watermark`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/watermark.xhtml) component which creates a JS based solution for legacy browser compatibility. So you don't definitely need to set a default value into the backing bean. Just use one of the following solutions:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Search: "/>  
<p:inputText id="search_input_id" value="#{watermarkBean.keyword}" 
    required="true" label="Keyword" placeholder="search" />
```

For legacy browsers:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Search: "/>  
<p:inputText id="search_input_id" value="#{watermarkBean.keyword}" 
    required="true" label="Keyword" />  
<p:watermark for="search_input_id" value="search" />
```

Also if using **JSF 2.2**, you can use its passthrough attributes. Adding `xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"` namespace to your page, you can achieve in the following way, both for [JSF](http://jsflive.wordpress.com/2013/08/08/jsf22-html5/) `h:inputText` and [Primefaces](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2714) `p:inputText`:

```
<h:inputText value="#{watermarkBean.keyword}"
    pt:placeholder="search" />
```

Or wrapping it into the tag with a TagHandler:

```
<h:inputText value="#{watermarkBean.keyword}">
    <f:passThroughAttribute name="placeholder"
        value="search"/>
</h:inputText>
```

Which creates [HTML 5 based](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) input with `placeholder` attribute:

```
<input placeholder="search">
```

Comment: Good answer. Note that OP tagged JSF 2.2 which offers a standard alternative. I'm not 100% sure if the OP tagged JSF 2.2 because he is really using it, or because he thinks to get more attention. I'm not seeing anything in question text nor in previously asked questions which confirms once more that he's really using JSF 2.2.

Comment: If you consider it, feel free to edit my answer or post a new one ;-)

Comment: @BalusC : I didn't understood your comment entirely!! Can you please elaborate? should I not have tagged JSF2.2? Right now my current JSF version is 2.1 but I'm willing to upgrade if that offers a feasible solution!

Comment: @Kishor: That comment was targeted on first version of this answer, before the edit. Click the link behind "edited X hours ago" below the answer and scroll down to see it.

Comment: No, you should absolutely not have tagged JSF 2.2 if you aren't using it and the question is not specifically about JSF 2.2. You also don't tag C#, Android, GWT, etc, right? Do not abuse tags for the sake of getting attention.

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery tweak would be:

```
<p:inputText styleClass="search" value="#{filter.search}"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('input.search).attr('placeholder','search');
</script>
```

You don't need to put an extra component in order to set attribute only, and you can mass-enrich inputs (if you need to).