# How to put placeholder in input jsf 2.1 without updating?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

I have a maven project that uses JSF 2.1

```
   <dependency>
           <groupId> org.jboss.spec.javax.faces </ groupId>
           <artifactId> jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec </ artifactId>
           <scope> provided </ scope>
         </ dependency>
```

I need to put in a placeholder h: input tried using:

```
xmlns: h = "http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns: f = "http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns: p = "http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns: ui = "http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns: ps = "http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"


<h: inputText id ="originPublic" styleClass ="form-control" ps:placeholder = "MyPlaceHolder" />
```

But I need to update the jsf for this, what I do because I'm afraid that reflects on the project and I need to change something else in the code. How could I put this placeholder without refreshing the jsf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8494384/4074715) offers several solutions. If you choose to implement custom renderer (option one), in one of the comments you can find [a sample implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11416458/4074715).