# h:commandLink not working as expected

Tags: jsf-2

I have a simple form with a commandLink inside, when I click the link I get this message in the browser console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'adp' of null` and when I replace the h:commandLink with h:commandButton, it works fine

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editSms" role="dialog"
            aria-labelledby="contactLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="contactLabel">Edit SMS template</h4>
                    </div>
                    <h:form id="editSmsForm">
                        <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 cfItem">
                                    <h:inputTextarea id="oldSms" readonly="true"
                                        value="#{homeBean.campaignDetails['Collateral_SMS_Text']}"
                                        rows="3" style="resize: none" class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 cfItem">
                                    <h:inputTextarea id="newSms"
                                        value="#{homeBean.campaignDetails['Collateral_SMS_Text']}"
                                        rows="3" style="resize: none" class="form-control"
                                        a:placeholder="New SMS... " />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">

                            <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal"
                                class="btn btn-outline btn-default">Close</a>
                            <h:commandLink actionListener="#{homeBean.test}" value="Save"
                                styleClass="btn btn-outline btn-primary">
                            </h:commandLink>

                        </div>
                    </h:form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: ... in MCVE flavor, of course.

Comment: This is wrong in your code: **a:placeholder** ="New SMS... ". Please check your question content and modify it in order to be reproducible.

Comment: @lametaweb: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8494264

Comment: Upsss, excuse me, I learned a new thing. Thanks @BalusC.