# Why does this placeholder attribute get passed through?

Tags: html, jsf

I am working on a JSF 2.1 application and I noticed some funny code that looks like this:

```
<h:inputText value="someValue" h:placeholder="Please enter a value" />
```

Notice that the placeholder is incorrectly prefixed with the JSF html namespace.
For some reason this code works and it results in the placeholder attribute being rendered.

I am using the OmniFaces RenderKitFactory, but as you can see below I haven't defined the placeholder attribute on HtmlInputText:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.HTML5_RENDER_KIT_PASSTHROUGH_ATTRIBUTES</param-name>
    <param-value>
    javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm=role;
    javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText=type;
    javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText=step;
    javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText=min;
    javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText=list;
    javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText=max;
    javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText=required;
    javax.faces.component.html.HtmlCommandButton=data-target;
    javax.faces.component.html.HtmlCommandButton=data-toggle;            
</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Why does this work?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets009.htm#sthref393 .. check this

Comment: Hi RïshïKêsh,

It is a JSF 2.1 application so it is not possible to use the passthrough attribute namespace...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494264/how-to-add-placeholder-attribute-to-jsf-input-component  ..

Comment: You are using omnifaces as you stated in another question. Most likely omnifaces is passing on this element (it is one of the otions in the referred answer)

Comment: Hi Kukeltje,

I have not specified the placeholder attribute for HtmlInputText on the RenderKitFactory. 
I edited the post to show the render kit configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Omnifaces HTML5 RenderKit supports several HTML5 attributes by default. The attributes that you specify in the `web.xml` are additional attributes.

The values which are supported by default are, as per [the JavaDoc](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/renderkit/Html5RenderKit.html),

- `UIForm`:

  - `autocomplete`
- `UISelectBoolean`, `UISelectOne` and `UISelectMany`:

  - `autofocus`
- `HtmlInputTextarea`:

  - `autofocus`
  - `maxlength`
  - `placeholder`
  - `spellcheck`
  - `wrap`
- `HtmlInputText`:

  - `type` (supported values are
      `text` (default), `search`, `email`, `url`, `tel`,
      `range`, `number` and `date`)
  - `autofocus`
  - `list`
  - `pattern`
  - `placeholder`
  - `spellcheck`
  - `min`
  - `max`
  - `step`

  (the latter three are only
    supported on `type` of `range`, `number` and `date`)
- `HtmlInputSecret`:

  - `autofocus`
  - `pattern`
  - `placeholder`
- `HtmlCommandButton`:

  - `autofocus`