# JSF: Custom attributes don't work with EL-expression?

Tags: html, jsf, jakarta-ee

I want to use custom attributes in standard JSF-components. Using or rather introducing a ResponseWriterWrapper as described here: [Adding custom attribute (HTML5) support to JSF 2.0 UIInput component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859520/adding-custom-attribute-html5-support-to-jsf-2-0-uiinput-component#answer-7886942), doesn't work when the custom attribute's value is an EL expression.

I introduced a custom renderer class for the component t:div and use my ResponseWriterWrapper to render custom attributes. So when writing

```
<t:div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
    ...
</t:div>
```

everything works fine!

But the following code doesn't work:

```
<t:div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="#{false}">
    ...
</t:div>
```

To be more detailed the attribute "data-collapsed" is not rendered because it is not part of the component's attribute list. I can see this when the component is passed to encodeBegin method.

Does somebody has an idea what's the reason for this and how I can solve this with a workaround or something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you tell us what data-collapsed will be used for? There may be a workaround of some sort.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The example is just intended to show the problem in a simple way. In this specific case the workaround is <div data-collapsed="#{false}>..</div>. The main problem remains, though: I want to use custom attributes on JSF-components in combination with **EL-expressions**. (BTW: "data-collapsed" is a jQuery Mobile attribute, and "data-*" is the preferred way in HTML5 for custom attributes.)

Comment: I've read lots of JSF component documentations and I've read a lot about "EL expression that must parse to <datatype>". I'm not very knowledgeable about this, but, what's supposedly the way to do an EL expression that parses to a certain datatype?

Comment: The datatype is defined by the getter/setter method in the component class. Check this example: http://blog.evolutionarydawn.com/2009/06/11/custom-jsf-component-12/ But I don't see your point here, could you explain?

Answer (score -1):

For custom attributes to be rendered in JSF they should be passed as Passthrough attributes which is possible in JSF2.2, not in 2.0 according to my knowledge.

**If you include following namespace (jsf 2.2):**

```
      xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
```

and define `<t:div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="#{false}">`it will render the data-collapsed attributes in you JSF component.

Its an option for you if upgrading jsf is possible.

Comment: Any reason why the answer is down voted? would Like to know so that I can learn in future.