# Input text returning null value

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

This might be simple problem, but I am not able to figure it out.

Here is my xhtml page:

```
*update p tag here, I am using primefaces*
<h:outputLabel for="Number" value="Number(100-800):" />
    <h:inputText id="number" name="number_Name" value="#{validationView.number}" label="Number">
        <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="100" maximum="800" />
    </h:inputText>

<p:commandButton value="S-ubmit" name="submit" actionListener="#{userBean1.method1}" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-check" validateClient="true"/>
```

This is my managed bean

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;

@ManagedBean(name="userBean1")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean1
{
    public void method(){
       String value = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
        getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("number_Name");          
       System.out.println("Value: "+value);
    }

    public void method1(ActionEvent event) {    
    String param =  (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("number_Name");
           System.out.println("Param: "+param);
    }
}
```

I tried both methods and in both cases it is printing `null` output. I imported el-impl-2,2.jar into my build path. I am using primefaces 5.1 and Tomcat7

Comment: I think you have to step back and do some jsf 101. This is an unusual way of trying to get to values of input fields.  It indeed does not work that way. You normally set values in beans and let the framework do all this plumbing for you

Comment: I would like to get this input variables to set and call store procedure.

Comment: @Kukeltje: indeed, see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, there is no attribute called `name` in `h:inputText`, if you really need to use that attribute, please refer to that question for more details: [How to specify name attribute in h:inputText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893876/how-to-specify-name-attribute-in-hinputtext)

So I will assume your `h:inputText` looks something like this:

```
<h:inputText id="number" value="#{validationView.number}" label="Number">
    <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="100" maximum="800" />
</h:inputText>
```

**Second**, in the `externalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get(key)` the `key` refers to the request parameters names included in the current request, which corresponds to the client ID (because `name` is autogenerated by JSF based on the client ID), so if for example your `h:inputText` is inside a form whose `id= "form"` then your client ID will be `"form:number"`, More  about [When and how is clientID generated in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351976/when-and-how-clientid-is-generated-in-jsf)

You can use your first method like this:

```
public void method(){

   String value = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("form:number");          
   System.out.println("Value: "+value);
}
```

In case you only know the component `id`  of your `h:inputText` and not it's client ID please refer to: [Find component by ID in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378437/find-component-by-id-in-jsf)

**Finnaly**, I think that the best way is to use the following method which make you benefit from the `ActionEvent`:

```
public void method(ActionEvent event) {        

     String param = (String) ((UIInput) event.getComponent().findComponent("form:number")).getValue();
     System.out.println("Param: "+param);

}
```

**NB:** please note that `event.getComponent()` gets the component that triggered the event which is `p:commandButton` (in your case) and not the `h:inputText`

Comment: while your answer is correct, wouldn't it be more logical to just make use of the validationView.number? It will be better maintainable, better IDE support, codecompletion and refactoring wise? To me it looks like the OP has e.g. a php background, switches to java/jsfand tries to solve the X problem in a Y(/php) way

Comment: But `number` is in the `validationView` managed bean, while the action is in another managed bean. So, to use number directly he will need to inject `validationView` inside `UserBean1`, then what if validationView is requestScoped? that wouldn't be possible using JSF managed beans

Comment: That is why I think a jsf 101 is better.  Also considering the other post.

Comment: But why JSF 1.1 would be better?!  There is a lot of new features in JSF 2.0 he will miss in that case (I want to send some links but sorry i am answering from my mobile phone)

Comment: Hahaha, sorry my bad. 101 is in courses you can follow the beginners one… no relation to jsf 1.1 http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14265/what-does-something-101-mean

Comment: Oh! Sorry I didn't knew  that, it's the first time i saw that and I thought you are talking about a JSF version :) and yes you are right :)