# JSF removes custom HTML component attributes

Tags: html, jsf, tags

I am using http://parsleyjs.org/ Javascript API for form validation for a JSF form.

I have included Parsley min JS in the header of the page.

An example code for Email validation input text :

```
 <h:inputText id="userName" class="editText"
value="#{administrator.userName}" data-trigger="change"
data-required="true" data-type="email" />
```

The tags data-trigger, data-required and data-type are defined for Parsley API.

But JSF removed those tags in the HTML generated.

```
<input id="j_idt22:userName" type="text" name="j_idt22:userName" class="editText">
```

What is the way to add those custom tags in HTML generated ?

Comment: Either you use JSF for HTML generation or you write it yourself. And what happens with unsupported tags, is JSF-implementation dependent.

Comment: ok. so whats the way forward and how should we implement custom tags ?

Comment: Something like here: http://myjavabuddy.blogspot.de/2013/04/writing-custom-components-for-jsf-20.html

Comment: Apart from the problem (which is easily sovled with a custom renderer or OmniFaces `Html5RenderKit`), why don't you just use JSF builtin validation? Client side validation is hackable/spoofable and completely unreliable. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013410/jsf2-validation-clientside-or-serverside/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write your own tags, it is sufficient to write your own renderer for the JSF-tags. A renderer which does not omit your custom attributes.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859520/adding-custom-attribute-html5-support-to-jsf-2-0-uiinput-component) on how to write & configure such a renderer for all your inputs.

Comment: This worked. But on applying the custom tags to input text, the generated HTML gives the tag to its parent element. In my case, its in a table, so the custom tags are assigned to a "td" element containing that input text. So what can be the solution for that ?

Comment: Even this issue also got solved by using the Renderer class given by @dileks on the link you provided !!