# JSF Custom component attribute properties with Annotations

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I would like to make a custom component 'foo' with an attribute called 'bar'.

In JSF 2.2 I can make the Component class in Java without any taglib file:

```
@FacesComponent(tagName = "foo", createTag = true)
public class Foo {

    @WhatShouldIUseHere(required = true, description = "example attribute")
    public Object getBar() { ... }

}
```

But I have problem with the bar attribute. Are there any annotation exists, which I can set required, description and other properties like in the taglib xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any annotation to do what you'd like.

If you don't know yet how to add attributes to your custom JSF components, you can look here : [Adding custom attribute (HTML5) support to JSF 2.0 UIInput component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859520/adding-custom-attribute-html5-support-to-jsf-2-0-uiinput-component)