# How to let JSF pass through HTML attributes

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, servlet-3.0

I am using Primefaces 3  in JSF 2 to make a search box. I need to add a non-standard attribute (x-webkit-speech) to the control so you would have something like this...

```
<p:autoComplete x-webkit-speech="x-webkit-speech" ... />
```

Since this attribute isn't part of the autoComplete control JSF gives me a 500 error. But when I remove it, the page renders fine. In general, how do you specify pass through attributes on a JSF tag so they are ignored?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6675592/617373

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSF by design ignores all custom attributes when rendering HTML.

If you're already on JSF 2.2+, simply specify it as [passthrough attribute](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/jsf-facelets009.html#_using_pass_through_attributes):

```
<html ... xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
...
<p:autoComplete a:x-webkit-speech="x-webkit-speech" ... />
```

If you're not on JSF 2.2 yet, then you need a custom renderer. This is in case of PrimeFaces `<p:autoComplete>` (and all other components) fortunately relatively simple. It's sufficient to override just the `renderPassThruAttributes()` method wherein you add the new attribute which you'd like to render to the `attrs` argument and finally delegate to the super method.

E.g.

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer;

public class MyAutoCompleteRenderer extends AutoCompleteRenderer {

    @Override
    protected void renderPassThruAttributes(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String[] attrs) throws IOException {
        String[] newAttrs = new String[attrs.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(attrs, 0, newAttrs, 0, attrs.length);
        newAttrs[attrs.length] = "x-webkit-speech";
        super.renderPassThruAttributes(facesContext, component, newAttrs);
    }

}
```

To get it to run, register it as follows in your webapp's `faces-config.xml`:

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
        <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.AutoCompleteRenderer</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.example.MyAutoCompleteRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

*(you can find out the component family and renderer type by looking at the source code of `AutoComplete` class, they're specified as `COMPONENT_FAMILY` and `RENDERER_TYPE` constants in there)*

No, the `@FacesRenderer` annotation simply won't work when the purpose is to override custom renderers which are by itselves already registered in a `faces-config.xml`.

Comment: Would it be possible to only have the renderer fire for certain autocomplete components?

Comment: No. You'd need to create a custom UI component. Just extending PrimeFaces `AutoComplete` and overridding `getRendererType()` to return a different value e.g. `com.example.MyAutoCompleteRenderer` ought to be sufficient. Register it in a `.taglib.xml` file and change `<renderer-type>` accordingly. Finally use that component instead as `<my:autoComplete>`.

Comment: where can I look up the render class to extend h:commandLink to accept custom html attributes?

Comment: Maby reference modern jsf passtrough attributes here? or point to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666472/custom-html-tag-attributes-are-not-rendered-by-jsf

Answer (score 1):

The most Tags can be extended, using the Attribute-Tag from JSF-Ext.

```
<html xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:e="http://java.sun.com/jsf/ext">
    <!-- ... -->
    <h:inputText id="name" value="#{bean.name}">
        <e:attribute name="placeholder" value="My Name"/>
    </h:inputText>
    <!-- ... -->
</html>
```

You can configure it via maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intersult</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-ext</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

JSF-Ext is a library from http://www.intersult.com/wiki/page/JSF%20Ext

Comment: What exactly does not work, could you provide an example? I'm using this feature all time in productive projects.

Comment: when I add this to pom.xml my persistence context is not recognized anymore ... strange thing, cann not find any reasonable cause

Comment: JSF-Ext is not designed to affect any persistence context

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is possible at all. I would add those attributes on the client side using javascript or jQuery.

You can put el expressions into your javascript code if you want to integrate server-side stuff.