# InputText PrimeFaces not applying maxlength

Tags: html, jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-mobile

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.4 with PrimeFaces Mobile 0.9.3. I specified maxlength in the inputText attribute, but it is not being rendered across in the HTML. My code:

```
<p:inputText id="price" value="#{bean.price}" styleClass="r-align" 
type="number" maxlength="9" validator="priceValidator"/>
```

Later I found that when I remove the "type" attribute from the tag, max length works.
Does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's simply because `maxlength` attribute is not supported on the [HTML5 `<input type="number">` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html), so it's reasonable to assume that PrimeFaces renderer won't emit it.

Instead, you should be using `min` and `max` attributes. Theoretically, you should be set with

```
<p:inputText type="number" max="999999999" />
```

However, this didn't work for me. It didn't render the `max` (nor the `min`) attribute altogether. This is in turn likely an oversight in the PrimeFaces component. Your best bet is to [report it as an issue to PrimeFaces guys](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list).

In the meanwhile, you can work this around by providing a custom renderer like this which basically adds the `min` and `max` attributes to the list of pass thru attributes:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer;

public class MyInputTextRenderer extends InputTextRenderer {

    @Override
    protected void renderPassThruAttributes(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String[] attrs) throws IOException {
        String[] newAttrs = new String[attrs.length + 2];
        System.arraycopy(attrs, 0, newAttrs, 0, attrs.length);
        newAttrs[newAttrs.length - 2] = "min";
        newAttrs[newAttrs.length - 1] = "max";
        super.renderPassThruAttributes(facesContext, component, newAttrs);
    }

}
```

which you can get to run by registering it as follows:

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
        <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.InputTextRenderer</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.example.MyInputTextRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

Note that passing through custom JSF component attributes will be natively supported in the  upcoming JSF 2.2, which allows among others HTML5 `data-*` attribute freedom.

#### See also:

- [How to let JSF pass through HTML attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484337/how-to-let-jsf-pass-through-html-attributes/10498902#10498902)

Comment: Hi BalusC, is it possible to load primefaces mobile only on mobile devices? so if the device is a mobile one we load the primefaces mobile using `<f:view renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE" />` and otherwise we don't load it so the normal primefaces library will load

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround you have to play with "maxValue":

For example, if your max length is: 8 so you should put max value as : 99999999 which is a number with 8 digits.

```
<p:inputNumber value="#{configBean.dependenciaUtils.selected.numTelefonoDependencia}"
                                       required="true"
                                       requiredMessage="Must put a value"
                                       maxlength="8"    
                                       maxValue="99999999"
                                       thousandSeparator=""
                                       decimalPlaces="0"
                                       />
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. Surely the easier one and the most praticable.

Answer (score 1):

```
<p:inputNumber maxlength="6" 
               maxValue="999999" 
               padControl="false" 
               thousandSeparator=""></p:inputNumber>
```

Set `maxlength` and `MaxValue` to set the maxlength for Primefaces inputnumber